# High Power/Range Electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism

Pretty new to electromagnetism but my team and I are working on a project so have some questions before we spend more money doing R&D.  We are looking to create a fairly small 10-20lb electromagnet.  What we need this to be able to do is create down force from a range of say 3-4 feet.

So when holding the magnet at around 3 feet it could create 20+ pounds of pull towards the metal sheet below(for a total pull of 40+lbs assuming the magnet itself is 20lbs).  Just curious if this would be possible in the scale that is needed.  We could pretty easily do the reverse and have the electromagnet at the bottom and the metal being pulled to the magnet but this is just not as practical for our project.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a magnetic field is on the order of the size of the magnet that creates it. You can focus the field so that it comes out one side of the magnet, but once the field emerges into air it will immediately spread out in order to minimize its energy. For example, it's impossible to make a magnetic jet that throws a magnetic field like a hose.

All that said, you only specified the weight of the electromagnet, not its size. So, if you had a large (but light) coil, several feet in diameter, you might be able to get a significant magnetic field at a distance of 3 feet. Doesn't seem likely to me that you'd get a 20 pound pull from it, though.

Comment: That's what I was worried about.  We were looking at around 1-2 foot diameter max and 20lbs was our low number.

Comment: I assume you can't go superconducting...

Comment: Well the application of this would have to work outside the lab on demand without any prep other than flipping a switch, so I doubt it.  Not super familiar with superconductivity or had considered it so I'm not sure if it is an practical option or not.

Comment: Last I heard, liquid nitrogen is cheaper than milk.